C++ configurable classes at compile-time
Given a class like a counter, I want compile-time configurable features (e.g. on under/overflow call a callback, ...), eg.

on a embedded device, not all features are needed.
it should be lean also in Debug Builds (no optimization!) due Flash-space is crucial.
nonetheless, it should provide all features if needed in other applications.

I tried Curiously Recurring Template Pattern to separate the configurable features, which separates variables and methods, but the derived class does not know if the features exist in that instance. So, to call only existing features, one need to utilize polymorphism - which is not resolved at compile-time.
The next best thing I came up with was to replace the feature member functions with empty stubs utilizing enable_if, but then all the unused member variables still exist.
So, for now, I have no solutions satisfying my goals. Is there any further option I missed?

Some short code examples would make it easier to understand what you want and to reply with helpful options. Maybe show how you would like a few versions of the "same" class to act depending on parameters. And though there are drawbacks, there is at least plain old #if FEATURE1.

that would not work on an per instance basis... :-)

What are you trying to optimise? RAM usage or disk space of compiled program?

Both... it just happened, that Code I used on PC and embedded Linux devices now also should serve on an Core M0 µC... it just has features I do not need in that case and should be configured down.

I've found that placing the configuration into a human readable text file is more useful than hardcoding the configuration.  With the text file, you can configure the software before runtime without having to recompile (create an executable and track the executable).

@ThomasMatthews I don't see your point. This would not reduce the footprint of the Code in the embedded enviroment - which by the way has no things like files...

@schnedan you could create such a file and then have your build chain consume it at compile-time while producing executables for each platform. Plenty of 3rd party cross-platform projects are configurable at compile-time, letting the configuration dictate which code is compiled.

A half decent linker will remove unused member functions in any event -even in a debug build, so it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  You are just adding complexity for probably no actual benefit.  Don't use templates at all if you want to avoid code-bloat - then your injection to conditional compilation is irrelevant.

@Clifford This (A half decent linker will remove unused member fct's...) I also expected, but with stm32 / gnu arm toolchain I definitely see a size penalty with any unused stuff left in the code. And by the way, I just tested my proposed solution with just that toolchain and it does exactly what I need / want. templates only add "code-bloat " when instanced for other types. And thats perfect C++ mindset: only pay for what you use.

@schnedan.  Fair enough. I am using ARM's LLVM / clang based toolchain (armcc v6 with armlink) and it aggressively removes dead code.  Good to know I am getting some value out of an expensive toolchain! ;-)

Proposed solution:
A combination of Metaprogramming conditional type selection + enable_if.
Replace turned off features with empty types (structures) and turned off methods with also empty ones.
The following code shows a counter class and 4 instances in main(): without any, with overflow, with underflow, and both available.
All generated from the same basic code, controlled by template parameters.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
 
using namespace std;
 
namespace Meta {
 
  //--- Select Type by condition
 
  template<bool cond, typename TRUE, typename FALSE> struct if_else{
    using type = FALSE;
  };
 
  template<typename TRUE, typename FALSE> struct if_else<true,TRUE,FALSE>{
    using type = TRUE;
  };
 
  template<bool cond, typename TRUE, typename FALSE> using if_else_t = typename if_else<cond,TRUE,FALSE>::type;
}
 
namespace Component {
 
enum class e_countertype{
  basic = 0,
  udfl  = 1,
  ovfl  = 2,
  both  = 3
};
using type_T = enum e_countertype;
 
//---
 
template<typename T> struct empty_st{
};
template<typename T> using empty_T = struct empty_st<T>;
 
//---
 
template<typename T> struct underflow_st{
  bool active{true};
  T udfl_treshold{0};
  std::function<void()> udfl_clbk;
};
template<typename T>using underflow_T = struct underflow_st<T>;
 
//---
 
template<typename T> struct overflow_st{
  bool active{true};
  T ovfl_treshold{0};
  std::function<void()> ovfl_clbk;
};
template<typename T>using overflow_T = struct overflow_st<T>;
 
template<typename T, typename CT=type_T, CT FEAT=e_countertype::basic> class Counter{
private:
 
  T counter{0};
  T satt_high{0};
  T satt_low{0};
 
  static constexpr bool const eval_overflow = (FEAT == e_countertype::ovfl)||(FEAT == e_countertype::both);
  static constexpr bool const eval_underflow = (FEAT == e_countertype::udfl)||(FEAT == e_countertype::both);
 
  [[no_unique_address]] Meta::if_else_t<eval_overflow,overflow_T<T>,empty_T<T>> overflow;
  [[no_unique_address]] Meta::if_else_t<eval_underflow,underflow_T<T>,empty_T<T>> underflow;
 
  //---
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::ovfl == FEAT) || (e_countertype::both == FEAT)), void>::type ovfl_impl()
  {
    if(counter > overflow.ovfl_treshold){
      if(overflow.active){
        if(overflow.ovfl_clbk){
          overflow.ovfl_clbk();
          overflow.active = false;
        }
      }
    }else{
      overflow.active = true;
    }
    return;
  }
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::basic == FEAT)  || (e_countertype::udfl == FEAT)), void>::type ovfl_impl()
  {
    return;
  }
 
  //---
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::udfl == FEAT) || (e_countertype::both == FEAT)), void>::type udfl_impl()
  {
    if(counter < underflow.udfl_treshold){
      if(underflow.active){
        if(underflow.udfl_clbk){
          underflow.udfl_clbk();
          underflow.active = false;
        }
      }
    }else{
      underflow.active = true;
    }
    return;
  }
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::basic == FEAT)  || (e_countertype::ovfl == FEAT)), void>::type udfl_impl()
  {
    return;
  }
 
  //---
 
  void ovfl_handler(){
    ovfl_impl();
    return;
  }
 
  void udfl_handler(){
    udfl_impl();
    return;
  }
 
public:
 
  void config(T sl, T sh){
    satt_high = sh;
    satt_low  = sl;
    return;
  }
 
  void increse(T inc){
    if( (satt_high-counter) > inc){
      counter += inc;
    }else{
      counter = satt_high;
    }
    ovfl_handler();
    return;
  }
 
  void decrese(T dec){
    if( (counter-satt_low) > dec){
      counter -= dec;
    }else{
      counter = satt_low;
    }
    udfl_handler();
    return;
  }
 
  T value(){
    return counter;
  }
 
  //---
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::ovfl == FEAT) || (e_countertype::both == FEAT)), void>::type ovfl_config(overflow_T<T>& config)
  {
    overflow.ovfl_treshold = config.ovfl_treshold;
    overflow.ovfl_clbk.swap(config.ovfl_clbk);
    overflow.active = true;
    return;
  }
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::basic == FEAT)  || (e_countertype::udfl == FEAT)), void>::type ovfl_config(overflow_T<T>& __attribute__((unused)) config)
  {
    return;
  }
 
  //---
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::udfl == FEAT) || (e_countertype::both == FEAT)), void>::type udfl_config(underflow_T<T>& config)
  {
    underflow.udfl_treshold = config.udfl_treshold;
    underflow.udfl_clbk.swap(config.udfl_clbk);
    underflow.active = true;
    return;
  }
 
  template<typename Q = CT>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, type_T>::value && ((e_countertype::basic == FEAT)  || (e_countertype::ovfl == FEAT)), void>::type udfl_config(underflow_T<T>& __attribute__((unused)) config)
  {
    return;
  }
 
};
 
} //namespace
 
using namespace Component;
 
int main(){
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
 
  {
    Counter<uint_fast16_t> cnt1;
    cnt1.config(0,10);
    cnt1.increse(15);
    cout << cnt1.value() << endl;
  }
  cout << "-----" << endl;
  {
    Counter<uint_fast16_t,type_T,e_countertype::ovfl> cnt2;
    cnt2.config(0,10);
    overflow_T<uint_fast16_t> oconfig = {.ovfl_treshold=5,
                            .ovfl_clbk=[](){
                              cout << "Overflow!" << endl;
                              return;
                            }};
    cnt2.ovfl_config(oconfig);
    cnt2.increse(15);
    cout << cnt2.value() << endl;
  }
  cout << "-----" << endl;
  {
    Counter<uint_fast16_t,type_T,e_countertype::udfl> cnt3;
    cnt3.config(0,10);
    underflow_T<uint_fast16_t> uconfig = {.udfl_treshold=5,
                                          .udfl_clbk=[](){
                                          cout << "Underflow!" << endl;
                                          return;
                                        }};
    cnt3.udfl_config(uconfig);
    cnt3.increse(15);
    cnt3.decrese(4);
    cnt3.decrese(4);
    cout << cnt3.value() << endl;
  }
  cout << "-----" << endl;
  {
    Counter<uint_fast16_t,type_T,e_countertype::both> cnt4;
    cnt4.config(0,10);
    overflow_T<uint_fast16_t> oconfig = {.ovfl_treshold=5,
                                         .ovfl_clbk=[](){
                                           cout << "Overflow!" << endl;
                                           return;
                                         }};
    cnt4.ovfl_config(oconfig);
    underflow_T<uint_fast16_t> uconfig = {.udfl_treshold=5,
                                          .udfl_clbk=[](){
                                            cout << "Underflow!" << endl;
                                            return;
                                          }};
    cnt4.udfl_config(uconfig);
    cnt4.increse(15);
    cnt4.decrese(4);
    cnt4.decrese(4);
    cout << cnt4.value() << endl;
  }
 
  return 0;
}


You can use inheritance to avoid the problem with std::enable_if:
template<int platform = 0>
struct PlatformFeatures {
};

template<>
struct PlatformFeatures<1> {
    int linux_feature = 42;
};

template<>
struct PlatformFeatures<2> {
    int windows_feature = 95;
};


template<bool is_debug = false>
struct DebugFeatures {
};

template<>
struct DebugFeatures<1> {
    int debug_only_feature = 100;
};


template<int platform, bool is_debug>
struct ConfigurableClass : PlatformFeatures<platform>, DebugFeatures<is_debug> {
    
};

#define PLATFORM_ID 1
#define DEBUG false

ConfigurableClass<PLATFORM_ID, DEBUG> linux_release;
std::cout << linux_release.linux_feature;
//std::cout << linux_release.windows_feature; // Will not compile
//std::cout << linux_release.debug_only_feature; // Will not compile


Hmm, I need to think about that... wouldn't I end up with reimplement 95% of the code over and over - once for each variant?

You need to implement each feature separately and pick up a subset of features using inheritance.

that does not work. see a counter class has up and down count methods. these need to call the handle-under/overlow methods. depending on the config these exist or not. An inheritance is not resolved at compiletime... so to get rid of the variables to handle under/overlow I would trade in the bloated vtable. This is why I said: I need a solution that does it at compile time!
